# Pandas Rolling Apply: apply() got an unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, pandas

I want to have a rolling apply on a dataframe however I have problem with my custom function which I want to have an additional input:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame(columns=['amount'])
df_test['amount'] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
mean = df_test['amount'].mean()

def rule(x,mean):
   x = x-mean
   return sum(x)

df_test['amount'].rolling(3).apply(rule,mean=mean)
```

This returns

```
TypeError: apply() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mean'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's different than normal `**kwargs`, here in `rolling.apply` basically it's a param that takes keyword args in a dict.

Docs [`rolling.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.apply.html) :

- **kwargs**: dict, default None.

  > Keyword arguments to be passed into func.

```
df_test['amount'].rolling(3).apply(rule, kwargs={'mean':mean})

0    NaN
1    NaN
2   -3.0
3    0.0
4    3.0
Name: amount, dtype: float64
```

One more way is to use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html#functools.partial) here.

```
from functools import partial
rule_mean = partial(rule, mean=mean)
df_test['amount'].rolling(3).apply(rule_mean)

0    NaN
1    NaN
2   -3.0
3    0.0
4    3.0
Name: amount, dtype: float64
```